# Prevent textmate from auto adding semicolon after colon

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles

Is there a way to prevent textmate from auto-typing a `;` after every `:` when editing CSS? I still want it to auto add closing brackets and curly braces. Just not semi-colons. Is this somewhere in the CSS textmate bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your bundle editor (Bundles -> Bundle Editor -> Show Bundle Editor)

At the top, where it says "Show All", change that to "Preferences".

Scroll down to CSS, you'll see one named "PropertyName". Delete it (highlight it and click the minus sign at the bottom of the editor).